# How can I get a new browser session when opening a new tab or window on Firefox/Chrome?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-security

How can I get a new browser session in my application 'localhost' when opening a new tab or window on Firefox and Chrome ??

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, right click > inspect element > network > tick disable cache and refresh. and same as other browser.